# PHP unlink permision denied for last file

Tags: php, permissions, unlink

I have following problem.

I have php script. It runs on virtual server Apache on windows PC.
Php script find out number of files in directory. It loads data from each file by php functions file_get_contents and file. It processed data and than delete the file and it continues with another files.

It processed all files. It deleted all files except tha last file. (It doesn't matter how many files are in directory always rest only last file.)

I tried function fclose (although i didn't used function fopen), I tried change atributes of files and directory by function chmod.

```
<?php  

$dir = '../scripts/nezpracovane/';
$files1 = scandir($dir);

$ap1 = 0;
while (array_key_exists($ap1, $files1))
{$ap1 = $ap1 + 1;}

$p_s = $ap1 - 1;
for($c_s = 1; $c_s < $p_s; $c_s = $c_s +1)
{
$adresa_x = "../scripts/nezpracovane/č.$c_s.txt";
$data_x = file_get_contents($adresa_x);

.....

$file = file($adresa_x);

.....

unlink ($adresa_x);
}


?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code? We cannot _guess_ your code. You have to post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you tried to read all files in folder using loop, such as `readdir()` function.

But the function also read the `.` and `..` folder. If you unlink it, permision denied.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

        // Do some stuff     
        unlink($entry); 

        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

(Sorry, I'm not good on English, I will try :) )